# How can I reference lambda name in serverless.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have `serverless.yml` as below:

```
functions:
  - myLambda:
      handler: src/lambdas.myLambdaHanlder
      name: myLambdaHandler
      timeout: 30

Resources:
  lambdaRole
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: ${myLambdaName}Role   # here, how can I reference myLambda function name in the role
```

I above code, I'd like to put lambda function name as the IAM role name prefix. How can I reference lambda function name there?

Comment: You dont have to set IAM roles up this way. You can just add IAM permissions directly to the function with the Serverless Framework: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#permissions

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

#### Option 1: Using Serverless Framework syntax `${}`

```
custom:
  myLambdaHandlerName: myLambdaHandler


functions:
  - myLambda:
      handler: src/lambdas.myLambdaHanlder
      name: ${self:custom.myLambdaHandlerName}
      timeout: 30

Resources:
  lambdaRole
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: ${self:custom.myLambdaHandlerName}Role
```

#### Option 2: Using CloudFormation intrinsic functions

```
functions:
  - myLambda:
      handler: src/lambdas.myLambdaHanlder
      name: myLambdaHandler
      timeout: 30

Resources:
  lambdaRole
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join [ "", [ !Ref myLambdaLambdaFunction, "Role" ] ]
```

Comment: I tried option1, I got the error `Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable ${self:custom. myLambdaHandlerName}. Please make sure the value of the property is a string.`. Is there any doc for how to use this syntax?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Looks like you have an extra space in between. Anyway, here is the [doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/).

Comment: It is a typo when I put the message. I got the error without the space. `${self:custom.myLambdaHandlerName}`. And why is it `custom`? Should it be `functions`? I tried `functions` still get the same error. It works to reference something defined in `custom` but can't reference lambda name